# Finding AWS security group duplicate entries

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli, aws-security-group

Is it possible to find duplications in the security groups in AWS?

For example :

Security group 1 has : 
   198.168.5.2/24 ,
   192.168.4.2/24 , 
   172.54.60.12/24

Security group 2 has : 
192.168.4.2/24 , 
172.54.60.12/24 ,
52.43.56.98/32

As you can see there are two exact same IPs in both SGs. Can this be done through AWS Cli ?

Comment: Yes you can describe the security groups using aws cli and parse the response to get the duplicates.

Comment: @franklinsijo can you please show me how?

Comment: Refer:[describe-security-groups](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-security-groups.html)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use the `ip-permission.cidr` filter for this. From the documentation:

> ip-permission.cidr - An IPv4 CIDR range that has been granted permission in a security group rule.

So you can use this to specify the CIDR range you want to check for, and it will list only the security groups containing a rule matching that CIDR range.

**Example command:**

```
aws ec2 describe-security-groups --filters Name=ip-permission.cidr,Values=172.54.60.12/24
```

**Further reading:**

- [AWS Documentation - aws ecs describe-security-groups](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-security-groups.html)
- [AWS Documentation - Using Shorthand Syntax with the AWS Command Line Interface](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/shorthand-syntax.html)